# How to display all child elements in JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display multiple child elements in jQuery but only the first child element gets displayed. I can force the browser to show all of them through Inspect and changing the css display from none to block. Can anyone help me find the problem in my code.I use Radio buttons, this is the code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#@radioButtonListSectionId input[type="radio"]
        [checked="checked"]').each(function () {
                ShowRadioButtonListDependentField(this, false);
            });
        });

        $('#@radioButtonListSectionId input[type="radio"]').change(function 
        () {
            var result = $(this).val();
            $('#@uniqueID-hidden').val(result);
            ShowRadioButtonListDependentField(this, false);

        });
        function ShowRadioButtonListDependentField(element, show) {
            debugger;
            var fieldKey = $(element).val(), children;
            var currentId = element.attributes["currentid"].value;
            if (currentId != 0) {
                if ($('.main-dialogbox.modal.fade.in').length > 0)
                    children = $('.modal-body .control-group[parentid=' + 
            currentId + ']');
                else if ($('.idea-task.open').length > 0)
                    children = $('.idea-task .control-group[parentid=' + 
           currentId + ']');
                else
                    children = $('.control-group[parentid=' + currentId + 
            ']');
                if ($(element).is(":checked") && $(element).is(":visible"))
                    show = true;
                else
                    show = false;
                children.hide();
                children.each(function () {
                    var keys = 
                this.attributes["parentOptionKey"].value.split("</br>");
                    var haschildren = this.attributes["haschildren"].value;
                    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                        if (keys[i] == fieldKey) {
                            if (show) {
                                $(this).show();
                                show = false;

                    $(this.getElementsByClassName("ishidden")).val("False");
                            } else {
                                $(this).hide();

                    $(this.getElementsByClassName("ishidden")).val("True");
                                if (haschildren.toLowerCase() == "true") {
                                    ShowCheckListDependentField(this, 
                     false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {

       $(this.getElementsByClassName("ishidden")).val("True");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: need to see the target HTML really

Comment: an running example ?